# Ubuntu 21 custom boot iso

Tags: boot, iso, 21.10

Can someone provide a link or instructions for building custom ISOs for Ubuntu 21. NOT Ubuntu 20. Ubuntu 21. Ubuntu 21 does not appear to use isolinux so any instructions that use isolinux is for Ubuntu 20.

Comment: There were two releases in 2020 and two releases in 2021, so your question seems confusing. Exactly which releases are you talking about? And how did you determine that "Ubuntu 21" --whatever that is-- does not use isolinux?

Comment: Are you trying to build an ISO file such as Cubic will do, or are you trying to build a bootable USB?

Comment: @user535733 My understanding is that Ubuntu 21.04 and later use the GRUB boot loader for both BIOS and UEFI boots and that Syslinux is no longer used. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=syslinux , Also if I open the 21.04 ISO there is no Isolinux folder.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron quite correct! And well said. My hope was that my question would do much same as your question - elicit a more answerable question. I suppose we shall see....

Comment: ISOs can be created differently per release as Ubuntu ensures they boot the same for all architectures for a given release; so 21.04 may boot differently to 21.10, which may boot differently to 20.10 (20.10 is different to 20.04 for example; 21.04 & 20.10 I think were ~same).  Ubuntu does have *year* releases; eg. Ubuntu Core 20 which are different again; but there is **no Ubuntu 21**. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was the *end of the development* cycle that started with Ubuntu 18.10; with 20.10 the start of the cycle which will end with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; there is no *year* correlation.

Comment: There is an Ubuntu 21.10 server ISO on their site for download for those who don't know. I don't understand the confusion on this.
After doing some testing I have determined that Ubuntu 21 install ISO is specifically built so you can NOT build custom install ISOs. Unless there is a hard to find way specifically sanctioned by Ubuntu.
There might be some possible hacks but I have doubts they will work.